# append is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body >


   <button onclick="me('${message}');">hello</button>
<div id="play">

</div>
<div id="p">

</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function me(mes)
   {

       switch(mes){
       case 'Knowing our Numbers':



        $("#p").append("<object id='objViewer' name='f'  classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0' width='550' height='400' id='intro to elianas website' align='middle'>"+
                "<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />"+
                "<param name='movie' width=400px height=400px value='test1.swf' />"+
                "<param name='quality' value='high' />"+
                "<param name='bgcolor' value='#1C140D' />"+
                "<EMBED  src='test1.swf' WIDTH='400px' HEIGHT='400px' quality='high' TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' NAME='intro' id='player' autostart='false'  allowScriptAccess='sameDomain' ShowControls='1' ShowStatusBar='0' ShowDisplay='0' ></EMBED><br/></object>"
                );
          alert(mes);     

       break;
       case 'Whole Numbers':
           alert(mes);
        break;      

           }

}


</script>

</html>
```

in the above code i am trying to append the html code in case statement but it is not working .how can i use the html code inside the case statement and based on that i need play the video

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add the jQuery library in the code as .append is the function in jQuery not of javascript.

Answer (score 2):

`append()` is the method of `jquery library`. To use this method you need to load `jQuery library` in your html page. **If you want to use without jQuery library try this below code.**

```
var div = document.getElementById('p');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<object id='objViewer' name='f'  classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0' width='550' height='400' id='intro to elianas website' align='middle'>"+
                "<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />"+
                "<param name='movie' width=400px height=400px value='test1.swf' />"+
                "<param name='quality' value='high' />"+
                "<param name='bgcolor' value='#1C140D' />"+
                "<EMBED  src='test1.swf' WIDTH='400px' HEIGHT='400px' quality='high' TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' NAME='intro' id='player' autostart='false'  allowScriptAccess='sameDomain' ShowControls='1' ShowStatusBar='0' ShowDisplay='0' ></EMBED><br/></object>";
```

or you can use like this also,

```
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML+="<object id='objViewer' name='f'  classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0' width='550' height='400' id='intro to elianas website' align='middle'>"+
                    "<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />"+
                    "<param name='movie' width=400px height=400px value='test1.swf' />"+
                    "<param name='quality' value='high' />"+
                    "<param name='bgcolor' value='#1C140D' />"+
                    "<EMBED  src='test1.swf' WIDTH='400px' HEIGHT='400px' quality='high' TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' NAME='intro' id='player' autostart='false'  allowScriptAccess='sameDomain' ShowControls='1' ShowStatusBar='0' ShowDisplay='0' ></EMBED><br/></object>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed `${message}` as string, but in your **switch** statement there is no case string related to that. That is the reason,

```
<button onclick="me('${message}');">hello</button>
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Try this,

```
 <button onclick="me('Knowing our Numbers');">hello</button>
```

Also, You need to load **jquery** library in this page.

Answer (score 0):

[`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is a function from the `jQuery` library. So, you need to [include jQuery in your code](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).
Also, make sure to include the `.append()` function inside `$(document).ready()` function.

Make sure to [read this](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) for a quick overview on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

its seems you didn't include any jquery libary so either include a jquery library to use `.append()`  you can download it from **http://jquery.com/download/** or you can also do the same thing with simple javascript .

```
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML+="<object id='objViewer' name='f'  classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0' width='550' height='400' id='intro to elianas website' align='middle'>"+
                    "<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />"+
                    "<param name='movie' width=400px height=400px value='test1.swf' />"+
                    "<param name='quality' value='high' />"+
                    "<param name='bgcolor' value='#1C140D' />"+
                    "<EMBED  src='test1.swf' WIDTH='400px' HEIGHT='400px' quality='high' TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' NAME='intro' id='player' autostart='false'  allowScriptAccess='sameDomain' ShowControls='1' ShowStatusBar='0' ShowDisplay='0' ></EMBED><br/></object>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js "></script><!--added-->

</head>

<body >


   <button onclick="me('Knowing our Numbers');">hello</button><!--edited-->
<div id="play">

</div>
<div id="p">

</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function me(mes)
   {

       switch(mes){
       case 'Knowing our Numbers':


// 
        // $("#p").append("<object id='objViewer' name='f'  classid='clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0' width='550' height='400' id='intro to elianas website' align='middle'>"+
                // "<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='sameDomain' />"+
                // "<param name='movie' width=400px height=400px value='test1.swf' />"+
                // "<param name='quality' value='high' />"+
                // "<param name='bgcolor' value='#1C140D' />"+
                // "<EMBED  src='test1.swf' WIDTH='400px' HEIGHT='400px' quality='high' TYPE='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' NAME='intro' id='player' autostart='false'  allowScriptAccess='sameDomain' ShowControls='1' ShowStatusBar='0' ShowDisplay='0' ></EMBED><br/></object>"
                // );
               $("#p").append("hiii");
          alert(mes);     

       break;
       case 'Whole Numbers':
           alert(mes);
        break;      

           }

}


</script>

</html>
```